# Pip install Zipline - Issue with the fortran compiler

Tags: python, numpy, module, pip, zipline

I am trying to install the zipline module with python, numpy and scipy are both up to date, as is pip, but I still get this error about fortran compiler - any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
C02PP0M7F8J2:~ bracea$ pip install zipline
Collecting zipline
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached zipline-0.8.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Collecting numpy==1.9.2
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
      InsecurePlatformWarning
      Using cached numpy-1.9.2-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
    Installing collected packages: numpy
      Found existing installation: numpy 1.10.1
        Uninstalling numpy-1.10.1:
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 311, in run
        root=options.root_path,
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 640, in install
        requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 716, in uninstall
        paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 125, in remove
        renames(path, new_path)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 315, in renames
        shutil.move(old, new)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
        os.unlink(src)
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.10.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Cython==0.22.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/2n/dj16vyjd5fjc6ppvzwbbhbw4_np44v/T/pip-build-CfLz1b/zipline/setup.py", line 199, in <module>
        packages=find_packages('.', include=['zipline', 'zipline.*']),
    TypeError: find_packages() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2n/dj16vyjd5fjc6ppvzwbbhbw4_np44v/T/pip-build-CfLz1b/zipline
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a permissions error to me.  Pip is trying to update the numpy package.  Check the following:

```
    Collecting numpy==1.9.2
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached numpy-1.9.2-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.10.1
    Uninstalling numpy-1.10.1:
```

Then the error:

```
    OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.10.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
```

Try doing this with root permissions.  I would however recommend you install this in a virtual environment however as not to modify the system python.